# How to save all the placed orders in "MyOrder" table in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, database, webforms, e-commerce, vs-web-site-project

I want to get all the placed orders saved in `MyOrder` table.

I am working on an e-commerce online store for car parts using ASP.NET. I'm using webforms and not MVC. For database I'm using Microsoft SQL Server.

I have a table `UserInformation` with the following columns:

[image]

The `MyOrder` table has the following columns:

[image]

And the `Cart` table these columns:

[image]

The `Cart` table is used to save the products in the cart for a particular users buying and "Amount" in the Cart table is the Quantity of the products and not the price.

`MyOrder` table is used to save all the placed orders list for Admin.

When the user click on "Continue Checkout" button. Then Users name, ProductID, Quantity, Date Purchased, Address, Price must get saved into the `MyOrder` table.

[image]

I used the following code for checkout button to save the details but it isn't working. No data gets saved in the `MyOrder` table. It always show Null value

```
protected void btnCheckOut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GarageDBEntities ord = new GarageDBEntities();

    var userId = Convert.ToInt32(User.Identity.GetUserId());
    var firstName = ord.UserInformations.Where(u => u.ID == userId).SingleOrDefault().FirstName;
    var products = (List<Product>)Session[User.Identity.GetUserId()];
    //var Address = ord.UserInformations.(u => u.ID == userId).singleordefault().Address;

    if (products != null)
    {
        foreach (var p in products)
        {
            MyOrder singleOrder = new MyOrder()
            {
                Username = firstName,
                ProductID = p.Id,
                //Quantity = p.Cart.Amount,
                DatePurchased = DateTime.Now
                //Address = Address,
                //Price = (double)p.Price
            };
            ord.MyOrders.Add(singleOrder);
            ord.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

I comment out few things just to check if its working, Project runs and orders get placed properly and the entry in the cart table gets updated but its not getting saved in the `MyOrder` table.

Without comment parts getting the following errors.

[image]

How to get all the placed orders by users to be saved in `MyOrder` table and how to remove all the errors shown in the screenshot?

Comment: For your errors;

1-) You can define your "Cart" class to the "Product" class, this way you will have a relationship between two objects. [link](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)
2-) Your "MyOrder" has a price field with int probably. And you are trying to assign double value to int. Check your fields.

Comment: @ErdemOzdemir there's already a relationship between my "Cart" table & "Product" table.